# How to combine 5000+ JS files into a single JS file for HTML head section?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am working on modernizing a legacy website that someone built over 11 years ago. The problem is that one of the HTML pages **contains over 5000+ JavaScript tags** in the head section of the HTML like so:

> **HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

<title>Data Items List</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
Var dtHash = new Object();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./datatypeJS/item1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./datatypeJS/item2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./datatypeJS/item3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./datatypeJS/item4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./datatypeJS/item5.js"></script>

//////and so on for the next 4900+ items!!

</script>
</head>
```

This obviously causes some browsers to crash (ie, mobile phones, tablets, etc) and desktop browsers can take up to 5minutes to load the page (I’m surprised it loads at all!) due to the large number of individual http requests the page makes for each 5000+ JS script file.

In the bottom of the HTML DOM it looks like a layout is generated dynamically via jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // CREATE THE LAYOUT
   document.getElementById("menuContent").innerHTML = menuContentVar.replace(/\.\.\/\.\.\//g, "../");
  tooltip(); 
  var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
document.getElementById("localAnchorDT").innerHTML = dtHash[hash]; 
       });
```

Here’s an example of what the actual script for item1.js (or any itemX.js) looks like.

> **item1.js:**

```
dtHash['Item1']="    <td> "+
"       <p class='col_txt' style='font-weight: bold;'>Item A<br/> </p>"+
"    </td>"+
"    <td class='myClass' colspan='2'> "+
"        <p class='col_txt' >Some text here blah b lah balh.</p>"+
"<br/><table border=1><tr>"+
"<td class='subTableHead'>Item 1 Name</td>"+
"</tr>"+
"<tr><td class='col_txt' align='left'><i>Blah blah blah</i> 
+
"</table></td>";
```

We can see that an object called `dtHash`  is created at the start of the HTML in the `<head>` and then JavaScript bracket notation for each item (e.g, `dtHash['Item1']` is used to lay out the template.

**My question is….is it possible to combine all 5000+ of these JS (itemx.js) files into a single minified JS file and only do a single http request in the HTML head section? I do plan to re-develop the website in the near future, but need a suggestion for on how to improve page performance.**

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I'm speechless.

Comment: I hear ya. I think it was a auto generated CMS of some sort, not sure. Crazy!

Comment: Look into Gulp and `gulp-concat` for a pretty easy way to concatenate files: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat

Comment: [Grunt The JavaScript Task Runner](https://gruntjs.com/) -  Task: [Concat task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)

Comment: Side note: that's vanilla JS, not jQuery

Comment: Would minifying 5000 files actually resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, you can, but that's not the biggest problem.  The real problem is: variable names, function names, Etc that will result in a clash of logic.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Is it possible that there are identical variables/function names currently in the different files? Wouldn't this also result in a clash of logic? Or are they differentiated by the different file source?

Comment: Also, I would consider waiting a few more years just so you could post the exact same question with over 9000 instead of 5000 ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the tip on Gulp/gulp-concat...I went with that path and it worked well locally -- will test it out tomorrow on the server. Will report how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can combine them, but that's not the biggest problem.

**The biggest problem:** Variable names, function names, Etc that will result in a clash of logic.  This problem is already happening for sure, specially in `for-loop` blocks.  A good way for separating that logic is creating namespaces to separate responsibilities, I.e:

```
var FileOne = {
    process: function() {...}
}

var FileTwo = {
    process: function() {...}
}

FileOne.process();
.
.
.
FileTwo.process();
```

The 5000+ files mustn't be removed and must be maintained for developing purposes. The task for concatenating them is a step that Gulp, Grunt, Etc., must execute in an continues delivery approach.

**I recommend the following resources:**

- [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/)
- [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/)
- [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)
- [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) *This is for continues delivery and for ease the execution of your tasks to concatenate the js files*

Answer (score 1):

~~~~~~~~~

<del>Why not just run a quick script that reads each file and appends it into the 1 file? You can run it locally with node.js then delete the tags. Just make sure the files are being appended in the same order to avoid dependency clashes.
node.js example:</del> **invalid code suggestion:**

```
fs = require('fs');

for(i=0 ; i < 5000 ; i++){
    const currentFile = fs.readFileSync(`item${i}.js', 'utf8');
    fs.appendFileSync("fullVersion.js", "\n" + currentFile)
}
```

~~~~~~~~~

**Edit:**

So as @elazer commented this can result in a very problematic clash of logic if similar variable names and/or functions are used across the different files. You could perhaps start thinking about how to differentiate them with the script but this becomes an overwhelming task which other tools suggested could do much better and quicker for you.

Comment: I think their question is asking what that 'quick script' is!

Comment: Yeah just added a little script example :-) There probable are online solution for it but maybe the sheer magnitude of files (5000!!!) would cramp those up. But iterating locally as the example i've added above should technically be easy CPUwise no?

Comment: No, that's not a good approach.  That task must be a step of a pipeline to concatenate the js files. For example, a task of Jenkins, Etc.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique You mean building a stream to eventually save the full file?

Comment: @CodeAt30 Yes.  The 5000+ files mustn't be removed and must be maintained for developing purposes.  The task for concatenating them is a step that Gulp, Grunt, Etc., must execute in an continues delivery approach.

Comment: @CodeAt30 that problem already exists among those js files.  The OP has a real challenge ahead to provide a good solution.